# Trying to create very simple closure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, groovy, closures

So i was watching this video and at 18:14 he has an example showcasing closures in the programming language "Groovy".
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7aYS9PcAITQ

Can JavaScript "save" instances in the same way using closures and if so, could somebody wrap up a little codesample for me to study?
I've been reading up on closures in JavaScript and essentially i know that if you have a function within a function and the outer function returns the inner function can be kept alive and that's part of what a closure is.

```
def makeCounter() {
    def very_local_variable = 0
    return { very_local_variable += 1 }
}

c1 = makeCounter()
c1()
c1()
c1()

c2 = makeCounter()

println "C1 = ${c1()}, C2 = ${c2()}"

OUTPUT and closures:
C1 = 4, C2 = 1
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: Javascript does have closures, and a quick Google search will tell you how they work, as we're not really interested in seeing some pseudo random code that has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I'm amused because http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1 almost always shows up as the top Related question in Javascript questions, but it's usually unrelated. This time it really _is_.

Comment: The code in the question is relevant, and its origin was explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function makeCounter() {
    var very_local_variable = 0;
    return function() { return very_local_variable += 1; };
}

var c1 = makeCounter();
c1();
c1();
c1();

var c2 = makeCounter();

console.log("C1 = ", c1(), " C2 = ", c2());
```

Comment: Wow, ok i get it thank you!